# How to open a notepad txt file in Visual Studio 2013 & display it in multiple textboxes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have to program a menuStrip button to open a txt file, each line of the file contains the details of a car (brand, model, year, no.miles, price, bodytype and gearbox). Each line has to be read separately and each piece of information has to be displayed in its corresponding text box.

I have this code, which displays the first line of text in file in a text box.

```
        { // opens txt file
            OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
            of.ShowDialog();
            StreamReader rf = new StreamReader(@"E:\VP Assignment\CarManager.txt");
            rtb_info.Text = rf.ReadLine();
            rf.Close();
        }
```

This opens the first line of text in a single text box, but I have no idea how to get it to display the relevant information in each text box.

The same line of text also opens no matter which file I select, I know it's because of the path I'm just not sure how to stop it from doing this.

Comment: Show your efforts first, then indicate where you are facing problem(s). Start with [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value from ShowDialog() to make sure the user actually selected something and didn't hit cancel, then use [OpenFileDialog.FileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the name of the file selected by the user:

```
        OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader rf = new StreamReader(of.FileName);
            rtb_info.Text = rf.ReadLine();
            // ... extract other "relevant" info and place into other controls ...
            rf.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the file to the end. `rf.ReadLine()`should continue until 
`EndofFile` (or any other pointers you use) returns true.